# Blank Form Fields on PDF Created with FPDM on Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, pdf, fonts

I am using FPDM to auto-fill a PDF form fields from a MySQL database via a Wordpress plugin. This works well and the form is generated and filled correctly. However, if I download the generated and filled PDF and send it to other people the form fields are blank to some but not to others.

I am thinking that this is may be a font issue but can't seem to nail down the issue. The template text is Times New Roman. The fields use Times Roman which when I look at Fonts on the PDF Properties pages shows a Custom font (Times Roman) with actual font name TimesNewRomanPSMT. The page also shows TimesNewRoman as an embedded font, like so...

[Filled PDF Fonts page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jT316.jpg)

Has anyone else experienced this problem?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's likely the issue is that FPDM does not create something called "appearances" for annotations (fields are a type of annotation), it just populates the value. An appearance allows a PDF viewer that doesn't know about annotations to display their *appearance* without needing to understand how to use the annotation's properties. Some viewers will generate appearances if they are not present, some won't.

You can test my assertion. If you're seeing blanks by default but see a value when you try to edit the field, then what I describe above is the problem.

Comment: Another tell for this situation is to open the document in Acrobat Reader, and close it without making any changes.  If Reader asks you if you want to save the changes made, that's a good indicator that it regenerated the annotation appearances.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I think that FPDM is creating the document correctly. The PDF fields are populated to begin with but editable by the recipient. The problem is that on some computers the fields simply don't display, there isn't even the grey background to indicate that fields exist in the document I've tried opening and saving the document but that makes no difference.